# A rod of length $2$ units whose one end is $(1,0,-1)$ and the other end touches the plane $x-2y+2z+4=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

A rod of length $2$ units whose one end is $(1,0,-1)$ and the other end touches the plane $x-2y+2z+4=0,$ then find the center of the region which the rod traces on the plane.

---

The rod sweeps out the figure which is a cone.
And in this question ,we need to find the center of the circle,which is projection of the apex point $P(1,0,-1)$ onto the plane $x-2y+2z+4=0$.
Let the center of the circle be $O(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.So the direction ratios of the line $OP$ are $(x_1-1,y_1,z_1+1)$.Since $OP$ and the normal to the plane are parallel so their direction ratios are proportional.
$\frac{x_1-1}{1}=\frac{y_1}{-2}=\frac{z_1+1}{2}=\lambda$(say)
Now $x_1=\lambda+1,y_1=-2\lambda,z_1=2\lambda-1$
Since $O$ lies on the plane $x-2y+2z+4=0$,So $x_1-2y_1+2z_1+4=0$
$\lambda+1-2(-2\lambda)+2(2\lambda-1)+4=0$
$\lambda=\frac{-1}{3}$
So the coordinates of the $O$ are $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{-5}{3})$

---

But the answer given in my book is $O(\frac{4}{3},\frac{-2}{3},\frac{1}{3})$
What is wrong in my method.Please help me.Is my answer correct or the one given in my book?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. The point given by the book is not even on the plane.